# How to pass js variable to controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a javascript variable to a controller angular and I can not do it, any suggestions?

My function:

```
function coordenadas(position) {
            var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
        }
```

My controller:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var moduloMapa = angular.module('BeLiga.indexMapControllers', ['google-maps']);

moduloMapa.controller('controlIndexMap', function($scope) {
    obtener_localizacion();
    $scope.center = {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    };

    $scope.zoom = 8;
});
```

I need to get the value of these two variables of function "coordenadas":

```
 var latitud;
 var longitud;
```

Comment: What's the definition of `obtener_localizacion()`? This function is being used, but is never defined in the code you've shown. Also, you must remember that `latitud` and `longitud` are variables that exist only in the scope of the `coordenadas` function.

Comment: I suggest you look into the `factory`, `service`, `constant` and `value` convenience functions on the angular module object.

Comment: If latitud and longitud are available in a parent scope you have access to them through inheritance.  If not, the angular way is to create a service that will provide these values to your controller.  Absolutely DO NOT even think about using $rootScope

Answer (score 1):

If variables exists on the page you should be able to used them with no problem as long they are define on the right scope.

Meaning that you should do something like this instead:

```
var latitud =0;
var longitud =0;

function coordenadas(position) {
   latitud = position.coords.latitude;
   longitud = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

What I would do probably in a case like this is to create a callback function instead:

```
function coordenadas(position, callback) {
  var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitud = position.coords.longitude;

  callback(latitud,longitud);
}
```

In the controller:

```
moduloMapa.controller('controlIndexMap', function($scope) {
    var somePositionObject = //not specified on the demo code.

    //invoking method with callback function to get both values.    
    coordenadas(somePositionObject,function(latitude, longitude){
      $scope.center = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
      };
    });

    $scope.zoom = 8;
});
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to make yourself dependant on global variables. In the Angular world, this should probably be solved using a `factory`, `service`, `constant` or `value` provider.

Comment: @robert.westerlund I totally agree, I was just trying to make a point on that. I just updated the answer with the approach I would personally follow but it took me longer to write

Answer (score 1):

You could probably put the `coordenadas` function in a `service`. Services, in some ways, are simply like modular wrappers for "global" functions, without having to use global functions (and you can just inject the service into whatever controller you want.)

For example:

```
moduloMapa.service('coordenadas', function() {
    return function(position) {
        return {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
    }
});

moduloMapa.controller('controlIndexMap',['coordenadas', function(coordenadas) {
    var latitude = coordenadas(/* whatever position */).latitude;

    // Now you've injected the 'coordenadas' service
    // You can dynamically return a latitude/longitude (in the controller's -- not global -- scope)
}]);
```